# Frustum Culling Plane Issue

Tags: opengl, java, frustum-culling

I have been having an issue with frustum culling, specifically culling planes (not to be confused with the frustum planes). I am using JOML in Java with the FrustumIntersection class, and using the projection matrix * the view matrix for the matrix (for the projection view matrix). The way I am finding the minimum and maximums for the AABB is by simply iterating through the vertices and multiplying that by the transformation matrix in JOML. Although this issue doesn't appear to happen with any meshes other than planes, here is a gif of what is happening:

As you can see, the plane is being culled when the camera moves on a certain axis when looking straight down (it should not be doing that), but only on that axis. Any answer that could hint me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
The issue was fixed, it was just a simple problem with the way I was storing the vertices, getting the axises intertwined.